# Error while working with construction try-except ValueError

Tags: python, valueerror, try-except

```
result = []
try:
    for i in range(len(ass)):
        int(df['sku'][i])
except ValueError:
    result.append(df['sku'][i])
```

I need to collect all the errors in a list. Tell me, please, the code above adds only the first error, I need everything.

After iterating over all sku values, only those that cannot be converted to int should be included in the list.

Comment: I think you want to put try in your for loop

Answer (score 2):

You can move the try...except inside the loop:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(ass)):
    try:
        int(df['sku'][i])
    except ValueError:
        result.append(df['sku'][i])
```

You can also use `isdigit()` with a list comprehension as follows:

```
result = [val for val in df['sku'] if val.isdigit()]
```

However, you should note that `isdigit()` will not work in some cases e.g. those with leading signs.

As an example, '+1' will convert to an integer type fine with `int()` but will return `False` with is `isdigit()`. Similarly, `-1` will convert fine with int() but return `False` with `isdigit()`.

Further information can be found int the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> **`str.isdigit()`**
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want the try-except in the loop:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(ass)):
    try:
        int(df['sku'][i])
    except ValueError:
        result.append(df['sku'][i])
```

But if it's really a list of non-digit SKUs you want,

```
result = [sku for sku in df['sku'] if not sku.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(ass)):
    try:
        int(df['sku'][i])
    except ValueError:
        result.append(df['sku'][i])
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. You helped a lot. Did what I wanted